# Can not validate input field using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I have an issue while validating input field using Angular.js.I need my input field only take numbers(`i.e-0,1...`) and no characters will be allowed.I am explaining my code below.

```
<div ng-class="{ 'myError': billdata.dis.$touched && billdata.dis.$invalid }">
<input type="text" name="dis" id="discount" class="form-control" placeholder="Add discount" ng-model="discount" ng-keypress="clearField('discount');" ng-keyup="setLatestSalePrice();" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]$/">
</div>
</div>
<div class="help-block" ng-messages="billdata.dis.$error" ng-if="billdata.dis.$touched">
<p ng-message="pattern" style="color:#F00;">This field needs only number(e.g-0,1..9).</p>
</div>
```

Here when i am typing the numbers the validation error message is also displaying.Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

A couple changes

- Change the input container to a `form` tag
- Give a name to the form tag eg `name='form'`
- Change the myError condition to `!form.$valid`
- Change the regex to `/^(\s*|\d+)$/` to allow empty string or numbers.

codepen http://codepen.io/Anthonyzou/pen/XXaBdy